# How to ask that how did a person know some certain information in the first place?

Tags: phrase-request

Asking someone "How did you know this?" implies that whatever they knew was the truth. Is there some other straight-foward answer that only asks how did the person come up to know this without actually implying that it is the truth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to talk about what a person believes to be true, without implying that it is true, you could use:

> Why do you believe that?

But this has the opposite effect: it suggests that you think that what they believe is *not* true.

Answer (score 1):

One might say "Where did you get this information" or "How did you manage to acquire this information". There are many ways to ask this, just change a few words to see which suits you best to "not imply that it is the truth"